# What is the best way to find the resistances values quickly?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

This is the summing amplifier. I want a quick and easy way to find the resistances  values (Standard 5% Resistances). I used traditional way which is plug and try but it takes too long.

This is the gai I want

[image]

Comment: what gain do you want, what ratio do you want per voltage. if you want a balanced summer then R1=R2=R3=R4 and start it with 1k.  if you want a weighted sum and E6 series... well a few lines of python would get that

Comment: Oh I forgot to include it.

Comment: Use this site http://jansson.us/resistors.html  400 ≈ 330k/820Ω; 300 ≈ 100kΩ/330Ω

Answer (score 1):

You won't get 300 / 200  / 400 ohms simply by two resistances. Commercially 1k and 100k are available.  But 200k, 300k those are not available. You need to make some series or parallel combination.

So, the best way is to use either 100 / 1k / 10k / 100k /1M to make any circuit. If you need 100x gain.  Use Rf = 100k, Ri = 1k.

For 300x,  Rf = 100+100+100. Ri = 1k.

For 400x, Rf = ( 100 + 100).  Ri = 1k || 1k.

If you want, you may use programmable resistance IC.

Comment: 200 = 100+100. 300 = 150+150. 400 = 220+180. Seems easy enough to me.

Comment: Yah it's easy. But at home people don't keep 100 types of resistors. So I suggested that. I threw away thousands of resistors last year and bought only multiples of 10. Just to keep my head cool.

Comment: Home people can order resistors just like any business from a supplier and usually have them in 2 days, sure keep some bodge values on hand, but work out what you need and order that?